# Est-ce correct de dire : « Cette chose m’insupporte » ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, verbes

Depuis ma tendre enfance j’entends cette tournure, je me suis toujours demandé si elle était grammaticalement correcte ou si c’était un abus. Quelqu’un peut-il éclairer ma lanterne ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te fait penser qu'elle est incorrecte ?

Comment: @Evpok : principalement d’avoir été repris par mes parents. « Cette chose est insupportable ». Maintenant je me demande pourquoi :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Voyons l'[article du TLF sur le verbe « insupporter »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/insupporter) :

> Fam. ou région. (Ouest).[…] Être insupportable à, provoquer un vif sentiment d'exaspération chez.[…] *Ce caquetage, qui m'insupportait autrefois, m'est agréable* (Goncourt, Journal,1870, p. 699).Cette vieille grue m'insupporte (H. Bataille, Maman Colibri,1904, III, 4, p. 22):

La solution est sans doute dans la remarque suivante :

> **Rem. Considéré comme incorrect grammaticalement : ,,R. le Bidois (Le Monde, 26 mars 1966) juge que ce verbe « assez prétentieux et faussement littéraire, ne s'est jamais réellement implanté dans la langue »`` (Dupré 1972).**

Cela dit, le TLF ne cite pas plus l'article. Impossible donc de savoir si cette opinion était sourcée. Cependant l'usage d'*insupporter* remonte à 1870 d'après le TLF, et l'[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/insupporter) donne ceci :

> XIXe siècle. Dérivé d'insupportable. Fam. Être insupportable à quelqu'un. Cette façon de parler m'insupporte. Il est plus correct de dire : Cette façon de parler m'est insupportable.

Donc familier, mais pas incorrect. Pour ce qui est de l'usage, comme ici on affectionne particulièrement les [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insupporte,exasp%C3%A8re&year_start=1700&year_end=2012&corpus=7&smoothing=3)…
[image: ngram for insupporte and exaspère]
Il est vrai que l'usage reste marginal.

En conclusion je ne pense pas qu'insupporter soit incorrect (d'autant plus qu'*incorrect* ne veut rien dire), mais il serait quand même intéressant de voir les sources de ce R. Le Bidois.

Answer (score 1):

Ça se dit, donc c'est correct, mais c'est étrangement construit, et unique dans son genre, je pense.

1. C'est insupportable.
2. Je ne le supporte pas.
3. Ça m'insupporte

Tentez la même suite a partir de inconcevable, inimaginable, impensable, inadmissible ou incroyable (par exemple).
Ça sonne bizarrement, non ?

Answer (score -1):

l'expression "m'insupporte"selon moi est correcte car elle est utilisé couramment dans le language des français. Alors, nous utilisions le language des français car nous ne Somme pas français.

Answer (score -4):

Je crois que la question n'est pas de savoir si le verbe « insupporter » peut être utilisé, mais plutôt de savoir s’il est juste que ce verbe soit précédé d'un « m' ».

Par exemple, ma femme devrait-elle dire: « j’insupporte le football » ou « le football m'insupporte ».

J'ai toujours trouvé que cette seconde tournure sonnait bizarrement (on a l'impression que c'est le football qui ne supporte pas ma femme), cependant c'est celle qui est la plus couramment utilisée. Je ne vois pas ce qui la rend correcte.

Comment: Pourtant, les précédents sont là: ça m'agace, ça m'irrite, ça m’énerve, ça m'horripile, ça m'exaspère, ça m'enrage, ça m'horrifie etc. Vu comme ça, malgré que *insupportable* diffère des adjectives correspondant à ces verbes (tous en -ant), il n'y a rien de surprenant à ce que cette construction syntaxique attire tout naturellement ce qui serait une exception vers elle. La langue **adore** les construction parallèle.

Comment: hu? je n’ai jamais entendu dire « j’insupporte le football ».

Comment: C'est [l'usage](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/est-ce-correct-de-dire-cette-chose-minsupporte/2081#2081) qui définit en fin de compte ce qui est correct, pas l'étymologie.